# Overriding python method to return object of correct class with extended data

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, overriding

Suppose I have a python class like:

```
class Meal(object):
   def __init__(self, starter, main="steak"):
       self.starter = starter
       self.main = main

   def new_meal_eaten_starter(self):
       return Meal("Eaten-%s" % self.starter, main=self.main)

   def __repr__(self):
       return "%s %s" % (self.starter, self.main)
```

Now I want to inherit from this class, adding some data:

```
class MealWithDessert(Meal):
    def __init__(self, dessert, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dessert = dessert

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.starter, self.main, self.dessert)
```

Of course this happens:

```
>>> x = MealWithDessert("cake", "salad", "pizza")
salad pizza cake
>>> x.new_meal_eaten_starter()
eaten-salad pizza
```

Of course what I want to see was eaten-salad pizza cake.
I can solve this problem by overriding the method to use the base method:

```
    def new_meal_eaten_starter(self):
        new_meal_no_dessert = super().new_eaten_starter()
        new_meal = MealWithDessert(self.dessert, new_meal_no_dessert.starter, main=new_meal_no_dessert.main)

    return new_meal
```

... but that is dammn ugly. Or by basically copying the base method (which violates DRY):

```
def new_meal_eaten_starter(self):
      return MealWithDessert(self.dessert, "Eaten-%s" % self.starter, main=self.main)
```

... and for more complex functions both options are really horrific. Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Beware PEP 8 states class names should follow Camel Case convention.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names. Otherwise they look like python function calls

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below achieved what you intend to do, I hope it helps

```
class Meal(object):
    def __init__(self, starter, main="steak"):
            self.starter = starter
            self.main = main

    def new_meal_same_starter(self, new_main):
        meal_class = globals()[self.__class__.__name__]
        new_args = self.__dict__.copy()
        new_args['starter'] = "Eaten-%s" % new_args['starter']
        new_args['main'] = new_main
        return meal_class(**new_args)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.starter, self.main)



class MealWithDessert(Meal):
    def __init__(self, dessert, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MealWithDessert, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.dessert = dessert

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.starter, self.main, self.dessert)


x = MealWithDessert("cake", "salad", "pizza")
print(x)
y = x.new_meal_same_starter("tofu")

a = Meal("Rice")
b = a.new_meal_same_starter("Bread")

print(a)
print(b)

print(y)

print(x)
```

Comment: Hi @samuel that works well for the trivial case where the overriden function is just replacing some data, but I'm interested in a more general problem where the overriden function is doing something more complicated. I've updated the example to make this clearer.

Comment: Hello @RobertCarver Though I can't picture how complex your implementation is meant to be, however I think the update I made covers the immediate need in the question. I've also updated the answer

Comment: Hi @Samuel that certainly works although not pretty at least it means the inherited class usage is clean. Will see if I can wrap in a decorator.

Comment: @RobertCarver Good to know it helps, at least for your immediate need. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -1):

I think problem here is following method in class meal

```
   def new_meal_same_starter(self, new_main):
       return Meal(self.starter, main=new_main)
```

You just need to update the main with new_main meal. So Try this:

```
   def new_meal_same_starter(self, new_main):
       self.main=new_main
```

If you need to return from the method, then override it:

```
   def new_meal_same_starter(self, new_main):
      return MealWithDessert(self.dessert, self.starter, main=new_main)
```

Comment: This modifies the same object instead of returning a new object, which is probably not what OP wanted (hence the `new` in the method name)

Comment: Hi @Vijay obviously this is a trivial piece of code for a much more complicated real example. The method new_meal_same_starter in practice could do something much more complex than just replace some data. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Hi @RobertCarver question still remains unclear.  1. Do you want to return new instance object or existing ones ?  2. Complex operation you are talking about works on current instance object or new instance object?

Comment: Return a new instance. The complex method in the basr class works on a current instance and returns a new instance of the base class.